# Why to use static with RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

Why is recommended to use `static` for a `class` extended from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` if I create a new instance of this class on the `onCreateViewHolder` method and I guess that instance is used for each item:

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview,parent,false);
    return new RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String textTop = noticias.get(position).getHora()+ noticias.get(position).getTemperatura();

    holder.textViewTop.setText(textTop);
    holder.textViewBot.setText(noticias.get(position).getTexto());

}


public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textViewTop;
    public TextView textViewBot;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        textViewTop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textViewBot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inner class contains reference to the outer class. So it means that every instance of your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` will contain reference to your `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

By making it `static` you avoid keeping this reference.

[Oracle Java Documentation - Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)